# Windows driver for Azure RTOS FileX with fault tolerant mode enabled

Tags: threadx, azure-rtos, windows-driver

I'm working on a development project which incorporates Azure ThreadX RTOS.  The embedded system contains an sdcard on which we would like to enable FileX's fault tolerant mode to make it more resilient to filesystem corruption.  The problem is that enabling fault tolerant mode causes the sdcard to no longer be recognized and readable by Windows.

I've searched but have been unable to find a Windows driver implementation that allows a fault tolerant enabled media device to be mounted in Windows.

A related question has been asked on [Microsoft's site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275659/read-filex-fault-tolerant-sd-card-in-windows) but no answer exists yet.